# Kotlin/Android : Cannot pass LiveData to customView with Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, viewmodel, android-custom-view

I've instanciated a Graph object in ViewModel and Im trying to pass it to the custom canvas view I made but I keep getting the messages that "Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference"

Bellow I post my code and error log.

Custom Canvas View

```
Class DesignCanvasView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : View(context) {

private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap
lateinit var graph : Graph
```

Fragment
class DesignFragment : Fragment() {

```
    private lateinit var binding : DesignFragmentBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: DesignViewModel

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = DesignFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.design_fragment, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DesignViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.graph.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            binding.designCanvasView.graph = it
        })

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
class DesignViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val graph = MutableLiveData<Graph>(Graph())
}
```

Error MSG
[image: Error]

EDIT
Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".screens.design.DesignFragment">

        <com.example.druggame.screens.design.DesignCanvasView
            android:id="@+id/designCanvasView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        </com.example.druggame.screens.design.DesignCanvasView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Make sure you post your code in the question as text, not images. I would recommend taking a look at [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I corrected the post.

Comment: Very strange, I have tested a similar example and it works fine, maybe post `R.layout.design_fragment`? Everything that I can see seems fine so far.

Comment: I updated  R.layout.design_fragment

Comment: It seems like `binding.designCanvasView` for unknown reason is a null

Comment: Yes it is, obviously I can't literally test your example because I don't have the rest of your project, but similar examples work fine on my end. Is your code in a public repository? If so I could have a proper look.

Comment: I've got it here: https://github.com/JLK700/canvas-app
Thank you very much for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't actually really data binding related but is because of your custom view. Your constructor takes in an `AttributeSet` as required for data binding, but you never pass it to the superclass (`View`). So instead it should look like this:

```kotlin
class DesignCanvasView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

---

Just a couple of other notes. You are recommended to use the individual binding classes to inflate your bindings, not the generic `DataBindingUtil` unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Secondly it is generally good practice to have all your view-related logic that *isn't* the initial binding in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`.

Then finally, although in your case the binding doesn't need a lifecycle owner, you should always stick to using the view's owner retreived with `viewLifecycleOwner` for your bindings (however, again, only if you don't have a specific not to).

Comment: ouu I understand and now it makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for solving the issue, your time and all usfull advices. I for sure will use all of them. Hava a gr8 day.